# Python: match word from two strings in list

Tags: python

I want to match the same word from two strings.

Code:

```
nn=['berry: blueberry','blueberry and raspberry','banana vs. apple','apple is delicious']
category=['blueberry','cherry']
for s in category:
    if any(x in s for x in nn):
        first_match = list(filter(lambda x: x in s, nn))[0]
        print(first_match)
```

Because berry is in 'berry: blueberry' and 'blueberry and raspberry', I want first match to print both of them, but it does not work.

Then I tried another way to code:

```
nn=['berry blueberry','blueberry and raspberry','banana vs. apple','apple is delicious']
#k=['benz','x5']
category=['blueberry','cherry']
for i in range(len(nn)):
    for s in category:
        if any(x in s for x in nn[i]):
            first_match = list(filter(lambda x: x in s, nn[i]))[0]
            print(first_match)
```

It printed:

```
b
e
b
e
b
e
l
e
```

The output is wrong. The result I expected is to print:

```
blueberry
blueberry
```

Comment: Can you describe what does you code do and what do you expect?

Comment: @ZisIsNotZis I did, but I edited it again.

Comment: Instead of the whole `if any(x in s for x in nn[i]): ...` block just do `if s in nn[i]: print(s)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of the code that pulls out the matching values in `nn`:

```
nn=['berry: blueberry','blueberry and raspberry',
    'banana vs. apple','apple is delicious']
category=['blueberry','cherry']
for s in category:
    matches = [x for x in nn if s in x]
    print(matches)
```

I think you can get the output printed the way you want from that. The trick is in the list comprehension for the matches; the missing part was how to do the right if check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in` operator like so:

```
berries = [s for s in nn if 'berry' in s]
```

berries gets set to `['berry: blueberry', 'blueberry and raspberry']`.

If want to use categories you could do this:

```
category=['blueberry','banana']
fresh_fruit = [s for c in category for s in nn if c in s]
```

`fresh_fruit` will be set to `['berry: blueberry', 'blueberry and raspberry', 'banana vs. apple']`